# Unwanted extra pages interspersed throughout \documentclass{exam}

Tags: blank-page

I'm fairly new to LaTeX and I'm running into an annoying issue. I'm producing several large, multiple-choice exams. Because each exam question is quite long, I want to start each new question on a new page.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question This is the question \#1. \newline
        \begin{parts}  
            \part This is sub-question \#1. \newline 
                \begin{oneparchoices}  
                    \choice This is choice 1. \newline 
                    \choice This is choice 2. \newline  
                    \choice This is choice 3. \newline 
                \end{oneparchoices} 
            \part This is sub-question \#2. \newline 
                \begin{oneparchoices}
                    \choice This is choice 1. \newline
                    \choice This is choice 2. \newline
                    \choice This is choice 3. \newline
                \end{oneparchoices} 
        \end{parts}
    \end{questions} \newpage %this \newpage command sporadically causes a blank page in the document, but does what I want the rest of the time.
\end{document}
```

At the end of each question I am starting a fresh page. On occasion the current page is already full, which means the **\newline** is written at the top of a fresh page which results in random blank pages throughout the exam. Is there a way to address this?

I realize I can scroll through the (very large) document and delete select \newline commands, but this would be stupidly time-consuming for the volume of documents I need to produce.

Cheers,

David.

Comment: your example doesn't show the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, you're right. It's not a bug, it's a product of where the \newline command is. I've marked the relevant line with a comment. Basically the exam questions' lengths are varied so the \newline command is often in the right position,  but occasionally not?

Comment: if you want help you need to show an example that demonstrates the problem, and not only claim that it sometimes happens.  We must be able to reproduce the problem to debug it.

Comment: but as you mention \newline (which is something else than \newpage): better remove them all, they look quite unneeded and can only harm.